# Which iPhone/iPod Hardware to Support for iPhone Game

Tags: iphone, hardware

I'm coming from a background of Android. I would like to figure out what kind of iBlah device hardware I need to support for iPhone game development; something like [Android's OS distribution stats](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), but for iBlah hardware.

From my research, it seems that I need to support both iPod and iPhone. But which versions of hardware? is 3G still used? What about 3GS?

For example, the -S phones seem to have dual core instead of single-core CPUs.

I also worry about performance. In Android, I had a severely low-end phone, which meant pretty much anything that ran okay there ran okay on other phones. For iPhone, how do I figure out what to support in terms of performance?

Comment: With the current release of iOS6, the minimum phone requirement is 3GS, it would make sense to use 3GS as a low end target.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the country, but in most places you can still find 3GS hardware, so if you plan to support as much hardware as possible, you should go with 3GS.

*however*

The difference between consecutive versions of the iPhone is so large that you may want to consider dropping support for 3GS (and maybe even 4 and dare I say 4S). That way you have a nice guaranteed minimum set of features. Remember that people with old devices are not precisely the people who impulse buy apps, much less games (this is *especially* true in the iPhone customer base). Your most valuable customers *will* have the latest gadgets from Cupertino.

It's like supporting Windows 2000 (and maybe even Windows XP) for the latest high-end games. Some people may still be using that platform, but supporting it may not necessarily be necessary for your interests.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291823/breakdown-of-ios-versions-being-used

Answer (score 0):

3GS is still being used. That's the oldest you'll support. I think you should also consider RAM.

The devices I have problems with are iPhone 3GS and iPod 4th gen not only because they have lower CPU, the RAM is also very low. If your game hogs too much memory, your game will keep crashing on it (even with proper memory management).

Here's the list:
iPhone 3GS
iPod 4th Gen
iPhone 4
iPhone 4S
iPhone 5
iPod 5th Gen (need to watch for this one)

Comment: Would you happen to know statistically the distribution of devices? That's the kind of thing I'm really after.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the actual values. I develop games for a company so this is a bit out of my responsibilities (somebody else is taking care of that). One thing I can say is that you still need to support iPod 4G if you want a bigger audience, there are still many users playing with that device.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode comes with a built-in fully featured emulator for both iphone and ipad, so you just need Xcode at minimum, you can code for iOS without having a real device.

If you care about optimization the only solution is always buying a real device.

Also depending on what sensors and controllers you want to use, you can just consider to buy an iPod touch if you are not interested in the differences between an iPod and an iPhone. I also should add the fact that the GPU is basically the same for the latest 3rd and 4th gen of Ipod touch, iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4, the only new GPU is in the iPhone 4s and is not so revolutionary, so i think that you can go for an ipod Touch if you want a real device for just testing your app.

Comment: Sorry, my question is about *iPhone* hardware minimum, not Mac hardware. I've updated my question accordingly; please let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: @ashes999 this is what the last part of my answer is about, also depending on what sensors and controllers you want to use, you can just consider to buy an iPod touch if you are not interested in the differences between an iPod and an iPhone. I also should add the fact that the GPU is basically the same for the latest 3rd and 4th gen of Ipod touch, iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4, the only new GPU is in the iPhone 4s and is not so revolutionary, so i think that you can go for an ipod Touch if you want a real device for just testing your app.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the bulk of your comment; that's the kind of stuff I'm asking about.

Comment: @ashes999 i have modified the first post.

Comment: @user827992 You're answering a question that isn't this question. Ashes999 is asking which iPhones he'll need to support, what kind of hardware is involved, etc. Talking about Xcode's emulator and optimization is irrelevant. I imagine a good answer would be something like: "You need to support these iPhones and these iPod touch versions, and these versions are so obscure only maybe 0.1% of people still use them" etc.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs this part is present in the last part of my answer